# Problem in using single quotes with preg_match and filter_var() functions together

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have run into a problem with filter_var(), preg_match(), and single quotes.

I am trying to sanitize and validate the last name for illegal characters. It works with almost everything but apparently last names containing single quotes like O'Corner are resulting in error.

I mean the $errors[] = 'Please use only alphabets, period, dash and spaces in the last name.'; is executing whenever I use single quotes in the user input field.

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Enter last name" maxlength="40" required value="<?php if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" title="Alphabets, quotes, dash, spaces and max 40 characters" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z' -]*$">
```

PHP code:

```
$lname = filter_var($_POST['last_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (!empty($lname)) {
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z' -]*$/", $lname)) {
        $errors[] = 'Please use only alphabets, period, dash and spaces in last name.';
    } else if (strlen($lname) > 40) {
        $errors[] = 'last name should not exceed 40 characters';
    } else {
        $lname = trim($lname);
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'Please enter your last name.';
}
```

I tried escaping the single quotes in the regular expression with backslash. But that did not work.

If I replace
`$lname = filter_var($_POST['last_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
with
`$lname = $_POST['lname'];`
it works fine.

But I'm still not sure what's wrong with using string containing single quotes and $lname = filter_var($_POST['last_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); with preg_match() method.
Could anyone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the fact the specific call to the filter_var function is encoding the single quote ' into the html entity &#39;

If you print the $lname variable in the browser, it will render as a regular single quote but in it's source it will not be a quote but the mentioned html entity.

Comment: Sir, what should I want to do to overcome this problem?

Comment: Do not use the filter_var - the regex is good enough. If you need to print the name on a webpage later, you can use htmlentities() or similar function. If you are going to insert it in database, use prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. If you are going to use it in more specific context, then use filter_var.